# Resolver dependency in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I have a route that activates 3 resolvers, a resolver is mapping a route parameter to an object, so it's something like a dictionary. The other 2 resolvers depend on this value in their work, so they should wait until the first one has resolved that part, then they can start.

Initially, there were only 2 resolvers, but to keep my code DRY I've taken the first part to a 3rd resolver, which lead me into this problem.

Is there support for such scenario in current Angular 4 version? or should I resort hacking my way using sideways??

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't miss anything, it sounds like the third resolver (which has the common code) is just a service, so you can inject it into the other 2 services and access it from there. You don't need it as resolver.

Comment: That's a good general solution, but if it's implemented as a service, I'll need to have access to route params in that service, passing it the route params from the resolver isn't a good solution since it means I'm resolving the params twice, is there a way to avoid that too?